# RSpec: factory not persisting after attribute changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

Im fairly new to RSpec but I am running into an issue (This is on Rails 4 fwiw). I have a simple model/factory test:

```
context "Scopes" do
    let (:widget) {create(:core_widget)}
  
    it ":active" do
      puts "Last Created widget:"
      puts pp(Core::Widget.last)
      widget.type = "active"
      widget.object_status_id = 15
      puts "After attribute change:"
      puts pp(Core::Widget.last)
      #puts pp(widget.attributes)
      expect(Core::Widget.active.ids).to include(widget.id)
    end
  end
```

This is testing out a very simple scope:

```
scope :active, -> { where(type: 'active', object_status_id:
                            [25, 15])
```

Pretty basic. However I noticed that checking (via the `puts` of the factory object`does NOT show the attribute changes (Changing`.type`to`active`and`.object_status_id`to`15`) when I re-print it?

I was told that `let` is lazily evaluated, and I understand that....but when I view the different object_id's when printing they are completely different. `let` should still have the same object reference in the same `it` block right?

Initially I thought it was a problem because I was doing `build_stubbed` on the factory creation. I also tried `let!` because I thought maybe that was the problem. Neither worked.

Comment: Are you missing `widget.save` after the attribute changes?  When you do `Core::Widget.last` you're getting a new instance of widget in memory, not the one with the non-persisted changes.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Ah yup, thats my old rusty rails skills coming back to bite me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening here is that you are updating the attributes of the model *in memory* without saving the changes to your database. Then when your `active` scope is called, a query is made to the database but since your changes haven't been saved to the database yet, the expected record is not found.

I would recommend checking out the various [`update*` functions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html) as a way to persist your changes to the database, or make sure you call `save` to save your changes.

For example, you can update your test to:

```rb
it ":active" do
  puts "Last Created widget:"
  puts pp(Core::Widget.last)
  widget.type = "active"
  widget.object_status_id = 15
  widget.save! # Add this line here to explicitly save the record to the DB
  puts "After attribute change:"
  puts pp(Core::Widget.last) # Now this should find the changed record in the DB as expected
  expect(Core::Widget.active.ids).to include(widget.id)
end
```

Comment: What is the difference between `!` after save?

Comment: The `save` method will return true or false depending on whether the save to the db was successful, but the `save!` method will raise an error if it is unsuccessful (more details [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save)). I like to use the `!` version in tests where I don't expect the save to fail so that I get a nice error message if it does actually fail. Otherwise, the save might fail silently and it makes debugging your tests a bit harder.